# What might cause `gatsby develop` to get stuck while building "development bundle"?

Tags: webpack, gatsby

I've made a Gatsby starter, and two separate people have reported to me that they are unable to run it, because it gets stuck while building a "development bundle". Neither development nor production build works. I'm unable to reproduce this issue on my own machine, but I would like to fix it for the people who want to use my starter. What could cause Gatsby to get stuck in this step, and is there any way that I could force the issue to reproduce on my machine?

Comment: Have you checked your Node versions? It happened to me a few times, that random behavior could be caused by a different version node and the consequent installation of packages and `node_modules`

Comment: This is obviously related to your environment, and not to Gatsby directly. As @FerranBuireu mentioned, I would make sure you're all using the same Node version (use nvm), and the same version of the Gatsby CLI, if you're using it (otherwise, try `npm run develop` instead of `gatsby develop` to make sure you're using the version from your local `node_modules`. Clean up your environment by reinstalling the modules and commit the lockfile, run `gatsby clean`, and see if it happens again. (I don't think we can help further over here without any logs, environment data, or the like)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answers! Turned out to be an issue in one of the Gatsby plugins, `styled-jsx-plugin-postcss`. Fixed by removing the plugin. Not sure why I could not reproduce on my machine, guessing it's related Node versions like you said.

Answer (score 8):

I solved it by running `gatsby clean` and then `gatsby develop`